# bounding absolute moments given probability of tails

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $P(X < t + c) \ge 1-e^{-t^2/2}$ for $t > 0$ and $c > 0$ is some known constant.

I am interested in deriving upper bounds for $E[|X|^k]$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

My approach is as follows:
$E[|X|^k]^{1/k} = E[|X-c+c|^k]^{1/k} \le E[|X-c|^k]^{1/k} + c$ by the triangle inequality.

Hence, it only remains to bound $E[|X-c|^k]^{1/k}$.

I'm going to exploit the fact that $E[|X-c|^k]^{1/k} = \int_0^{\infty} P(|X-c|^k \ge u)\,du = \int_0^{\infty} ku^{k-1} P(|X-c| \ge u)\,du$.

However, since $P(|X-c| \ge u) \ge P(X-c\ge u)$, I could not invoke the tail probability that I have for $X$.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? If I have results on $P(d - t < X) \ge 1-e^{-t^2/2}$ for some constant $d$, $t>0$, will that be needed here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following approach

$$
E[|X|^k]=\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{k-1}P(|X|>t)\,dt = \int_{0}^c t^{k-1}P(|X|>t)\,dt + \int_{c}^{\infty} t^{k-1}P(|X|>t)\,dt \\
\leq c^{k-1} + \int_{0}^{\infty} (z+c)^{k-1}P(|X|>z+c)\,dz \leq c^{k-1} + \int_{0}^{\infty} (z+c)^{k-1}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,dz.
$$
In the last inequality, we have used $P(|X|>z+c) \leq e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$.

You will need some assumptions on the lower tail. Otherwise, you can construct a random variable whose upper tail is Gaussian and lower tail is like Cauchy, and therefore you will not be able to prove any meaningful upper bound even for $E|X|$. Let me know if this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Thanks, Suman. I may be wrong but there seems to be a typo with the $z-c$. I presume you made a change of variables $t = z+c$? Also, the limits of the integral need to be updated.

Anyway, I do have information on the lower tail but it's not in the form that I like. The Gaussian tail on $X$ is actually  Corollary 5.35 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027.pdf . $X$ in my case is $s_{max}(A)$ as in the paper. However, I cannot seem to express Corollary 5.35 into the form $P(|s_{max}(A)-c| \ge t) \le e^{-t^2/2}$. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I corrected the typos, let me get back after checking the link that you have sent. Best

Comment: Suman, nevermind, I just found the answer to my problem after some thought. Theorem 5.8 of http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/Teaching/36755/F16/Scribed_Lectures/LEC0914.pdf is what I need and my approach above only needs to be adapted. Thanks so much!

Comment: Correct, I was about to type a similar argument but good that you have already found it, Vaguely: you do not need symmetric tail (like the one in my answer) bounds but you will just need some tail bounds. Then you can cut off the integral according to your available bounds.